# SQL queries in access

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2007

I have 5 tables in access that are IDTable, ArtistTable, BandTable, AlbumTable, and SongTable.

I should search, insert, delete and update by Artist ID. First I tried to combine IDs like giving the IDs depending on each other as;

```
-------------------- BandTable ----------------------
BandID (PK)     BandName
   1            Guns and Roses
   2            Mumford and Sons

------------------- ArtistTable ----------------------
ArtistID (PK)     BandID    ArtistName        BirthDate    City     Country
   1                 2      Marcus Mumford    31.01.1987   London   UK
   2                 2      Winston Marshall  
   3                 2      Ben Lovett   
   4                 2      Ted Dwane   

-------------------- AlbumTable ---------------------
AlbumID (PK)   ArtistID     AlbumName       Year    Genre       AlbumImage
   1               1        Sigh No More    2009    Folk Rock
   2               1        Babel

-------------------- SongTable ----------------------
SongID (PK)    AlbumID     SongName             Duration   Lyricist
   1              1        Little Lion Man        4.06     Mumford and Sons
   2              1        Winter Winds
   3              2        I Will Wait
   4              2        Lover of the Light
```

However, every band has an artist(s) but not every artist has a band so I couldn't make out Join statement here.

Then I tried to combine all IDs in IDTable which are in the other tables as below;

```
--------------------- IDTable ------------------------
ID (PK)      ArtistID        BandID      AlbumID     SongID
1                1              2            1           1
2                1              2            1           2
3                1              2            2           3
4                1              2            2           4
5                2              2            1           1
6                2              2            1           2
7                2              2            2           3
8                2              2            2           4

------------------- ArtistTable ----------------------
ArtistID (PK)   ArtistName        BirthDate    City     Country
   1            Marcus Mumford    31.01.1987   London   UK
   2            Winston Marshall  
   3            Ben Lovett   
   4            Ted Dwane   

-------------------- BandTable ----------------------
BandID (PK)    BandName
   1           Guns and Roses
   2           Mumford and Sons

-------------------- AlbumTable ---------------------
AlbumID (PK)   AlbumName       Year    Genre       AlbumImage
   1           Sigh No More    2009    Folk Rock
   2           Babel

-------------------- SongTable ----------------------
SongID (PK)    SongName             Duration   Lyricist
   1           Little Lion Man        4.06     Mumford and Sons
   2           Winter Winds
   3           I Will Wait
   4           Lover of the Light
```

(PK) means Primary Key.

The code is:

```
String query = "SELECT "
              + " ArtistTable.ArtistName"
              + " ArtistTable.BirthDate"
              + " ArtistTable.City"
              + " ArtistTable.Country"
              + " BandTable.BandName,"
              + " AlbumTable.AlbumName"
              + " AlbumTable.Year"
              + " AlbumTable.Genre"
              + " SongTable.SongName"
              + " SongTable.Duration"
              + " SongTable.Lyricist"

              + "FROM (((IDTable " 

              + "INNER JOIN ArtistTable ON IDTable.ArtistID = ArtistTable.ArtistID) "
              + "INNER JOIN BandTable ON IDTable.BandID = BandTable.BandID) "
              + "INNER JOIN AlbumTable ON IDTable.AlbumID = AlbumTable.AlbumID) "
              + "INNER JOIN SongTable ON IDTable.SongID = SongTable.SongID "

              + "WHERE IDTable.ID=" +ID+";";
```

but it didn't work. I do not know if I gave the primary keys wrong or the code is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Elaborate Didn't work. You got an error or you didnt get the expected results?

Comment: Include commas between the items in the fields list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String query = "SELECT "
              + " ArtistTable.ArtistName,"
              + " ArtistTable.BirthDate,"
              + " ArtistTable.City,"
              + " ArtistTable.Country,"
              + " BandTable.BandName,"
              + " AlbumTable.AlbumName,"
              + " AlbumTable.Year,"
              + " AlbumTable.Genre,"
              + " SongTable.SongName,"
              + " SongTable.Duration,"
              + " SongTable.Lyricist"

              + "FROM IDTable " 

              + "INNER JOIN ArtistTable ON IDTable.ArtistID = ArtistTable.ArtistID "
              + "INNER JOIN BandTable ON IDTable.BandID = BandTable.BandID "
              + "INNER JOIN AlbumTable ON IDTable.AlbumID = AlbumTable.AlbumID "
              + "INNER JOIN SongTable ON IDTable.SongID = SongTable.SongID "

              + "WHERE IDTable.ID=" +ID+";";
```

Comment: I also now tried your way but it says the same error

Comment: Query updated, had missing commas as @hanup mentioned. Try again.

Comment: @user3489347 Can you build and test your query with the Access query designer?  If so, get it working there first and deal with Java later.

Comment: Yes I added missing commas thank you :) now Ill try with Query Designer

Comment: I've changed the tables and codes by query design's sql but it now doesn't give any error but run and just waiting